How do you make gunicorn forward SIGINT to uvicorn when running inside Docker?
I have a script running inside Docker (using wsl2), started with CMD, that is behaving strangely w.r.t. SIGINT signals. This is the script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python manage.py init_db

exec gunicorn foobar.asgi:application \
  --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
  --graceful-timeout 5 \
  --log-level debug \
  -w 4

The problem is that when I press Ctrl+C, gunicorn ends up having to forcefully kill the running uvicorn workers. I see the following errors after 5 seconds:
^C[2024-10-29 21:15:35 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2024-10-29 21:15:40 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[2024-10-29 21:15:40 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[2024-10-29 21:15:40 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[2024-10-29 21:15:40 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

I have found three workarounds of sorts, which may be useful to help understand what is going on.

Bash into the container and start the script from inside. Now Ctrl+C seems to work better, because now the uvicorn workers quit on time, but gunicorn still prints some errors:

^C[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: int
... worker shutdown cleanup output omitted
[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:15) was sent SIGINT!
[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:14) was sent SIGINT!
[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:13) was sent SIGINT!
[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) was sent SIGINT!
[2024-10-29 21:21:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:11) was sent SIGINT!


Add -it to the docker run command:

docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -v $(pwd):/app foobar:latest

This results in the same behavior as with 1.

Replace exec with manual signal forwarding:

#!/usr/bin/env bash

python manage.py init_db

# Forward SIGINT signal
trap 'kill -INT $PID' INT

# Start Gunicorn
gunicorn foobar.asgi:application \
  --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
  --graceful-timeout 5 \
  --log-level debug \
  -w 4 & \
PID=$!

# Wait for Gunicorn process
wait $PID

Now, pressing Ctrl+C, I only see the following, but I notice that the workers don't seem to run any of their shutdown code anymore:
^C[2024-10-29 21:26:37 +0000] [7] [INFO] Handling signal: int

What's going on here, and what's a good way to make sure that the uvicorn workers shutdown properly on Ctrl+C?
EDIT: Here's my Dockerfile, since a commenter asked me about it. And note that I get the same Ctrl+C behavior if I run gunicorn directly from the Dockerfile, instead of running the start-django bash script:
CMD ["gunicorn", "foobar.asgi:application", \
     "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", \
     "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", \
     "--graceful-timeout", "5", \
     "--log-level", "debug", \
     "-w", "4"]

Dockerfile:
# >>> Build stage <<<
FROM python:3.11-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Install C toolchain and C build-time dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
    # gcc, make, etc.
    build-essential \
    # psycopg2 client libs and header files for building psycopg2
    libpq-dev && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create virtual environment and add it to PATH.
RUN python -m venv /venv
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy requirements and install.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
  pip install --no-cache-dir --no-warn-script-location -r requirements.txt


# >>> Run stage <<<
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Install C runtime dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
    # psycopg2 runtime lib
    libpq5 && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create and switch to appuser.
RUN groupadd -r appuser && \
  useradd --no-log-init -r -g appuser appuser && \
  chown -R appuser:appuser /app
USER appuser

# Copy virtual environment from the build stage and add it to PATH.
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser --from=build /venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Copy the rest of the application code.
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser . .

# Set Python environment variables.
# Prevent Python from writing .pyc files
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
# Ensure output is sent to stdout/stderr immediately
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Start server.
CMD ["/app/deployment/start-django"]


EDIT2: I'm seeing the exact same behavior on a completely new Django project with only these three dependencies in my requirements.txt, using the same Dockerfile and bash script from above:
django
gunicorn
uvicorn[standard]


What is the actual Dockerfile?  The actual script seems a little odd; can you make the gunicorn command be the image's CMD, without wrapping it in a script (and without the unnecessary intermediate environment variable)?

you tried docker run --init ...

@DavidMaze My bash script is a little longer, and i conditionally build up the GUNICORN_CMD based on other environment variables. I removed that other stuff from the script but forgot to also remove the variable. Note that the script behaves the same with or without GUNICORN_CMD. Note also that I see the same behavior if I run gunicorn directly from the Dockerfile (added it to the question now).

@ChrisBecke Yes, I tried docker run --init ... and it didn't help. I also tried installing tini and setting ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"], but no luck there either.
